# Centos 6.5. Как отключить RC4?

Tags: apache, centos

Нужно отключить RC4 на двух серверах с centos7 и centos 6.5

На centos 7 открываю /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf, пишу в файл:

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
```

Перезагружаю апач. Конфиг отрабатывает, -SSLv3 и RC4 отключены.

На centos 6.5 /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf, пишу:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
```

перезагружаю апач, -SSLv3 отключен, RC4 включен. Как отключить RC4?

Comment: вы не указали, какая версия программы *apache* стоит на втором вашем компьютере.

Comment: httpd-2.2.15-39.el6.centos.x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте убрать `RC4` (вы ведь исключаете этот пункт в последнем элементе: `!RC4`) и исключить `EECDH+aRSA+RC4` (добавив `!` перед ним).

т.е., вместо:

> SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"

используйте:

> SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 !EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"

Comment: очень странно, сначала заработало, потом я не смог повторить условий возникновения ошибки.